# How to perform a specific intersection operation sets?

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I have a list of sets in python as `A=[{1, 'CL1'},{1, 'CL2'},{2, 'CL3'},{2, 'CL9'}]`. Here int values represent student number and string value represents the class category. I want to perform an intersection operation in such a way that Class X and Class Y share the following students. For example CL1, CL2 have student 1 in common. Similarly CL3, CL9 have student 2 in common. How to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
A=[{1, 'CL1'},{1, 'CL3'},{2, 'CL3'},{2, 'CL9'}]
l = [tuple(row) for row in A]

dic = {}
for row in l:
    if row[0] in dic:
        dic[row[0]].append(row[1])
    else:
        dic[row[0]] = [row[1]]

for key in dic:
    if len(dic[key]) > 1:
        print(key, ':', dic[key])
```

You can generate a dictionary where student is the key and value is a list containing all classes which contain the student. Then you can print all the dic keys and values for which the list has length greater than 1.

Comment: This may not be the most effective way though.

Answer (score 0):

Use intersection between sets.

```
A[0].intersection(A[1])
A[2].intersection(A[3])
```

Comment: I tried this but still not getting it how would it give me only classes that share common students.

Comment: suppose you have A=[{1,2,3, 'CL1'},{1, 'CL2'},{2, 'CL3'},{2, 'CL9'}]
now the intersection of A[0] and A[1] will return {1} which they have common student and same goes for A[2]&A[3].                                                          
print (A[0].intersection(A[1]))
print (A[2].intersection(A[3]))